# Required GCP IAM permissions for accessing/managing Google Maps/Places API

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I searched through the roles in the IAM role management and was unable to find roles to access and manage `APIs & Service` in GCP so that I can give a person access to specific API Services only.

How can I achieve that?

Cheers & Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Enable Service Account Admin for IAM account